# Selling my software suite to another company (acquisition)

Tags: finance, investment

I am trying to calculate a price to sell my software suite to another company. Let say my revenue is \$500,000 a year with only about \$50,000 costs each year. The rate of growth of revenue has been 20% per year.

Any idea how I should price my software?

The buyer might be a company with between 300-10.000 employees and making billions.

Please excuse me for being a novice - I am just a developer. Also, any links to further information is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question isn't in scope for the economics site. It might be in scope for personal finance, but that doesn't seem right, either.

Comment: I could only suggest meta for migration, not personal finance.